Upgrading PHP to 8.3.9 from 8.2.12 on Windows 11 - cURL is not working
Steps I am taking:

Fresh install of XAMPP, which uses PHP 8.2.12.
After install, I confirm that cURL shows enabled in my phpinfo and my local coding files work as expected.
I renamed the existing php folder in my xampp directory to php_old.
I downloaded a thread-safe version of php 8.3.9 and unzip to a new 'php' folder in xampp directory.
Checking phpinfo again, it does show that my php version was updated to 8.3.9, but cURL is completely missing.

The only thing I know to check:
I went to the php.ini-development file, uncommented 'extension=curl', and saved it as a new php.ini. Still nothing in phpinfo. However, when I added the full file path in the file (C:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll) into the INI file, cURL does finally show up in phpinfo as enabled and the info reading 8.7.0-DEV.
Now, my local files does appear to be firing cURL because I am no longer getting a fatal error, but I am not getting any JSON/response back from the endpoint that I am hitting. Whereas in 8.2.12 I was getting the JSON back just fine.
I feel like I am missing something completely stupid here.

"but I am not getting any JSON/response back from the endpoint that I am hitting" - do you get an empty response? Or a timeout? What do curl_errno / curl_error have to say?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl may be helpful - you can debug in detail and hopefully get some useful diagnostics

Thanks @CBroe that helped me get a step to resolution.

Thanks to @Cbroe - figured out the problem.
My cURL was looking for a cert that was not defined in the php.ini-development file, but it was in my older php.ini file in my backup. Once I added that cert file path to curl.cainfo ("C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"), my cURL responded correctly.
So the steps that I believe need to be done to fully upgrade/rectify the issue:

I needed to add the full file path for extension=curl. So extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll
I needed to add the curl.cainfo file path for the cert "C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
Save the ini-development file as a new php.ini file.

